# AngularJS API Login using OAuth

Tags: angularjs, authentication, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to learn how to use OAuth 2.0 on AngularJS to do logins to APIs. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial/some code on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Learning about logins is not Angular specific and is more about the following factors:

- Getting set up with an Authorization Server
- Knowing what security libraries to use
- Understanding how an SPA can login and get an access token
- Understanding the OAuth messages and which fields are important
- Calling an API with the token and handling 401 responses
- Understanding how APIs validate tokens and use claims

If these aspects interest you, have a look at my [visual tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/), which has a code sample that you can run on your local PC.

My early code samples use plain TypeScript and I update to ReactJS later. You should be able to do the same thing for Angular.